# How to update a table after I edited a field from another related table?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently working on a project that has an accounts management section where the system admin creates the user accounts.

The [Users] table has a column named "Organization_name", which is the user's represented organization. After submitting the form, "Organization_name" will then be also added to the [Organization] table, under the [name] field. The two tables are related by the "user_id" column (taken from the "id" column of the [Users]).

I managed to create a working code to add a [Users] account that also adds the organization_name to the [Organization] table, although now I'm wondering how can I make a function that will also edit the rows in the [Organization] table whenever I edit the fields in [User].

(ex. I changed the "organization_name" field in [Users] with id=1 from "Organization A" to "Organization B," the "name" field in [Organization] with user_id=1 should also change from "Organization A" to "Organization B" too).

NOTE: "role_id" determines what kind of account permissions a user account will have, it doesn't affect the question but I'll leave it in the code snippet below just in case.

I'll attach the codes that I used below:

**UserController.php**

```
private static function createUser(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new User();
        $user->email = $request->get('email');
        $user->organization_name = $request->get('organization_name');
        $user->password = Hash::make($request->get('password'));
        $user->role_id = $request->get('role_id');
        return $user;
    }

private static function createSubUser(Request $request, $user_id)
    {
        $role_id = $request->get('role_id');
        if($role_id == 1)
        {
            $sub_user = new Organization();
            $sub_user->user_id = $user_id;
            $sub_user->name = $request->get('organization_name');

        }
        elseif($role_id == 2)
        {
            $sub_user = new Staff();
            $sub_user->user_id = $user_id;
        }
        elseif($role_id == 3)
        {
            $sub_user = new Administrator();
            $sub_user->user_id = $user_id;
        }
        return $sub_user;
     }

public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'organization_name' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
        ]);

        if($validator->fails()){
            return response()->json($validator->errors()->toJson(), 400);
        }

        $user = static::createUser($request);
        $user->save();
        $sub_user = static::createSubUser($request, $user->id);
        $sub_user->save();

    }

public function updateUserInfo(Request $request)
    {
        $user = User::find($request->id);
         if($user->email == $request->email){
            $check_email = false;
        } 
        else{
            $check_user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
            if (!empty($check_user)) {
                $check_email = true;
            }
            else {
                $check_email = false;
            }
        }

        if($check_email === true)
        {
            return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'error' => "User with the registered email of {$request->input('email')} already exists",
            ]);
        }
        else 
        {
            $user = User::where('id', $request->id)->update([
                'email' => $request->input('email'),
                'organization_name' => $request->input('organization_name'),
                'role_id' => $request->input('role_id')

            ]);
            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'user' => $user
            ]);
        }

    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Where is the jQuery relevance here?

Comment: it might be easier to look a making a trigger on the tables to do the update. OR have a separate table with the organizations names. Then a fk in the tables that relate to that name

Comment: @hurnhu how do I make this trigger to update? I already have a separate table with the organization's name, the table [Organization] (it's under the createSubUser function], and the user_id is what relates the said table to the [Users] table.

Comment: assuming you are using mysql http://www.mysqltutorial.org/create-the-first-trigger-in-mysql.aspx. If you already have a separate table, why are org names also stored on the [User] table?

Comment: @hurnhu the org names in [Users] table are fillable, whatever is inputted there will be mirrored and created to the [Organization] table.

I've successfully done this part, I was just wondering how can I update the field "name" from [Organization] table whenever I update the "organization_name" field from [Users] table

Answer (score 1):

Why you need to add user_id on organization??
An organzation should have many students or users.
No need to store organization_name on users table just save the id of organization.
When you need to update organization name just update it on organization table.
Because you don't need to change in user table you just save here id. 
Feel free to comment if you have any confussion.

Comment: the system I am making is a list of Organization presidents, which is why there is only 1 representative (the President) per organization.

There is an Organization_name column on [Users] table because when they sign-up, they put the name of their Organization in it. The system then adds the Organization they've put in the [Organizations] table, with the following as columns:

- user_id
- name (the organization_name)

Can you suggest a way so when I update Organization_Name in the [Users] table, it will reflect too in the Name column of the [Organizations] table?